# Encryption using Cipher from javax

Tags: java, ios, encryption, robovm

I need encryption in my app and thought about using [javax.crypto.Cipher](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) for that. I wonder if I can use it for desktop, android and iOS and if [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.com/) supports it.

I want to use the following algorithm:

`Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`

Comment: Why don't you try it out on RoboVM? It seems to be free to try.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support Java. Instead use CommonCrypto, part of Apple's Security framework.

Common Crypto does support AES (128 & 256 bit keys), CBC mode and PCKS7Padding.

Note: in the context of AES PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding are the same. See: [crypto stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I wanted to know If I can use Cipher using RoboVM. It is a JavaVM that runs on iOS. Because crypto is a special topic I wonder if this is also supported.

Comment: One potential issue is the special ARM crypto instructions. My guess is that the conversion from Java bytecodes would not utilize them. But the performance might not be an issue.